# Remove focus from buttons in html form

Tags: html

I have a form which contains some labels,below this some buttons are there,problem is onload of the form the very first button is focused.How to remove the focus?

HTML code:

```
<td align="center" color="black">
<button type="submit" class="pd" name="Close" onclick="window.close();">
                 Close</button>
<button type="submit"  class="pd" name="Submit" onclick="Submit();">Submit</button>
</td>
```

Please suggest some answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like the following.

```
document.getElementById('Id').blur();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change button type to button instead of submit and write javascript for actions.